# receive push notification when a certain date expirespush notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that has the Firebase Realtime Database as database.
In the app there are different products that expire after a certain time.

The database contains the expiry date and the exact time. How do I get the user to receive a push notification if the product is only available for 10 minutes, even if the app is completely closed?

Do I have to save the data on my device and send a local push notification from there?

Currently the user only receives a push notification when a new product is added.

Answer (score 1):

A "local push notification" isn't really a thing. There are local notifications and push notifications. Push notifications are sent (pushed) from your server, through Apple's APNS (Apple Push Notification Server) and to your app's user.

You can schedule local notifications locally for some future time. There's really no difference to the user. It displays a message in the notification center which the user can tap to wake up your app, even if it wasn't running when the notification "goes off."

It sounds like you want to schedule a local notification.

If the trigger comes from your server then you could trigger a push notification. Those are also displayed to the user in the notification center whether your app is running or not.

Comment: Do I have to set up anything on Firebase or do I have to set up a timer in my app?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your use-case is. I suggest reading up on UserNotifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/